# How to write firewalld rule with rich language

Tags: networking, linux-networking, firewalld

How can I write a rule for `firewalld` using rich language which restricts packets from a particular port and particular protocol. For IP tables I wrote a rule like:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter SCTP 0 -p sctp --dport 2905 -j ACCEPT
```

How do I convert it into rich language? Also how are we intended to define state in rich language?

Comment: What do you mean by "rich language"?

Comment: you can find it at following link:https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html#Configuring_Complex_Firewall_Rules_with_the_Rich-Language_Syntax